# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when assigning to struct returned by malloc_default_zone() on iOS Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, assembly, exc-bad-access

I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in the iPhone Simulator when I try to change the pointer to the current malloc function pointer with my own implementation:

```
malloc_zone_t *zone = malloc_default_zone();
zone->malloc = my_malloc;
```

Assembly:

```
0x2b73:  movl   $0, %ecx
0x2b78:  leal   -40(%ebp), %edx
0x2b7b:  movl   -92(%ebp), %esi
0x2b7e:  movl   13828(%esi), %edi
0x2b84:  movl   %eax, -76(%ebp)
0x2b87:  movl   -76(%ebp), %eax
0x2b8a:  movl   %edi, 12(%eax) <------ EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x675100c
0x2b8d:  movl   16836(%esi), %eax
0x2b93:  movl   16588(%esi), %edi
0x2b99:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x2b9c:  movl   %edi, 4(%esp)
0x2ba0:  movl   %ecx, -132(%ebp)
0x2ba6:  movl   %edx, -136(%ebp)
```

I also get an error even if I try to change a simple field like version:

```
zone->version = 9;
```

Answer (score 1):

Old but here's an answer.
The default zone is write protected, for a workaround, see:
http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/53362/trunk/WebKitTools/DumpRenderTree/mac

Answer (score -1):

As I know malloc_default_zone() used by in OS X only. You can check this fact in help.
So this function may not works right on iPhone.